# How to save input fields of accompanying checkboxes?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a list a checkboxes with accompanying input text fields. If the user checks a box, the accompanying text field will be add to an array.

I am new to PHP and was wondering if anyone can help me in the right direction.

Should I use a for loop, foreach, while, unique "name" for each input, or something else?

Below is what I have so far.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $array = array();
  while(isset($_POST['check'])){
    if(!isset($_POST[$some_text]) || empty($_POST[$some_text])){
      echo "Please include your text for each checkbox you selected.";
      exit();
    }
   $array[] = $_POST['some_text];
 }
}
?>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="check"><input type="text name="some_text">
<input type="checkbox" name="check"><input type="text name="some_text">
<input type="checkbox" name="check"><input type="text name="some_text">
<!-- I might have around 100 of these -->
<!-- submit button here -->
</form>
```

Comment: It will be more better if you use loop.

Comment: @raveenanigam Can you please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need a way to associate your checkboxes with their corresponding text fields, and a way to tell them apart. For example:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1"><input type="text name="text1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="2"><input type="text name="text2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="3"><input type="text name="text3">
</form>
```

Now you can loop through it as follows:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['check']) && is_array($_POST['check']) && !empty($_POST['check'])) {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($_POST['check'] as $value) {
            $text_field = 'text' . $value;
            if (!isset($_POST[$text_field]) || trim($_POST[$text_field]) == '') {
                echo "Please include your text for each checkbox you selected.";
                exit;
            }
            $array[] = $_POST[$text_field];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank YOU

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $select = array();
 foreach($_POST['check'] as $key => $selected){
    $select[$key] = $selected;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. When I submit, this error pops up. Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

for($i=0; $i<100; $i++)
{
    if($_POST['check_'.$i])
    {
        $array[] = $_POST['input_'.$i];
    }
}
}
?>
```

#################### HTML

```
<form method="post" action="">
<?php for($i=0; $i<100; $i++) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_<?php echo $i ?>"><input type="text" name="input_<?php echo $i ?>">
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```